# Is there an easy way to iterate over an NSArray backwards?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I've got an `NSArray` and have to iterate over it in a special case backwards, so that I first look at the last element. It's for performance reasons: If the last one just makes no sense, all previous ones can be ignored. So I'd like to break the loop. But that won't work if I iterate forward from 0 to n. I need to go from n to 0. Maybe there is a method or function I don't know about, so I wouldn't have to re-invent the wheel here.

Comment: "How can I reverse a NSArray in Objective-C?" is a completely different question.

Comment: Swift: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24508592/how-to-iterate-for-loop-in-reverse-order-in-swift

Answer (score 200, accepted):

To add on the other answers, you can use `-[NSArray reverseObjectEnumerator]` in combination with the fast enumeration feature in Objective-C 2.0 (available in Leopard, iPhone):

```
for (id someObject in [myArray reverseObjectEnumerator])
{
    // print some info
    NSLog([someObject description]);
}
```

Source with some more info: http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/05/fast-enumeration-clarifications.html

Comment: Is this considered fast enumeration, and is this faster than a regular c for loop that starts from `[myArray count]-1`? How do you iterate over an `NSString` backwards?

Comment: I don’t have any links here right now but there is a video somewhere (could’ve been a WWDC) where an Apple engineer explains how fast enumeration works and why it is fast. It outperforms both index-based NSArray enumeration and classic Foundation enumerators and, depending on the scenario, by a lot.

Comment: I have to run a reverse for loop on a dictionary, how to do so?

Comment: @AshwinG Your question doesn't make sense, as `NSDictionary`s don't have an 'order'. You can enumerate them in any real order, unless you first order the keys/values.

Answer (score 17):

Since this is for performace, you have a number of options and would be well advised to try them all to see which works best.

- `[array enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:…]`
- `-[NSArray reverseObjectEnumerator]`
- [Create a reverse copy of the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586370/how-can-i-reverse-a-nsarray-in-objective-c) and then iterate through that normally
- Use a standard C for loop and start and work backwards through the array.

More extreme methods (if performance is super-critical)

- Read up on how Cocoa implements fast object enumeration and create your own equivalent in reverse.
- Use a C or C++ array.

There may be others. In which case, anyone feel free to add it.

Comment: I would say that the enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse is the best answer, especially if you need to know what index you are on. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 12):

From [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programming_Mac_OS_X_with_Cocoa_for_beginners/Containers_-_arrays,_and_dictionarys):

```
 NSEnumerator* myIterator = [myArray reverseObjectEnumerator];
 id anObject;

 while( anObject = [myIterator nextObject])
 {
     /* do something useful with anObject */
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[NsArray reverseObjectEnumerator]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = ((int)[array count] - 1); i > -1; i--) {
    NSLog(@"element: %@",array[i]);
}
```

Comment: This does not detect changes to a mutable array instance during enumeration (elements, count). Otherwise probably a little faster than creating an NSEnumerator object.