# Sort an NSArray in Descending Order

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I have an `NSArray` of `NSNumber` objects that I have successfully sorted in ascending order using the following:

```
[myArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]
```

However, I need to sort this in *descending* order. I take it that `compare:` only sorts in ascending order. While I can go about reversing the `NSArray`, I am curious as to whether or not there is a more simpler or more effective way of going about doing this.

**EDIT**: I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844189/is-there-an-easy-way-to-iterate-over-an-nsarray-backwards) which provides a simple way to reverse iterate an `NSArray`:

```
for (id someObject in [myArray reverseObjectEnumerator])
```

This works fine, I guess it's a nice simple solution, but I'm curious as to whether or not there is a way to specify sorting in descending order.

Comment: This answer is short, sweet and clever: http://stackoverflow.com/a/586529/999934

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Use a sort descriptor

```
NSSortDescriptor* sortOrder = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"self" 
                                                            ascending: NO];
return [myArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject: sortOrder]];
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using this and I like how it's really simple.

Comment: @Blaenk: Hi, I've rolled back your edit because `arrayWithObject:` was not a typo.  There really is such a method for NSArray.  Also, the spaces after the colons are deliberate.

Comment: The typo was that you had arayWithObject, not arrayWithObject. Then I got carried away. But that's fine.

Answer (score 12):

Another way, imo, is also nice: write another reverseCompare with category:

```
@implementation NSNumber (Utility)

- (NSComparisonResult)reverseCompare:(NSNumber *)aNumber {
  return [aNumber compare:self];
}
```

The good thing is that you can reuse everywhere and don't have to write the loop with reverse iterate. The bad thing is that you have to write more code:)

Answer (score 7):

use sortarrayusingcomparator method like that

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:
^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2){
        return [obj2 compare:obj1];
    }];
```

by reversing the order of objects you will obtain a descending order

Comment: It works like a charm,  I used to sort an array of NSString.                           You need a sorted array to apply this.

Answer (score 6):

There are a few ways:

1. Write a comparison function and pass it to `sortUsingFunction:context:`.
2. Use `sortUsingComparator:`, which takes a block. (Only available in Mac OS X 10.6 and later and iOS 4.0 and later.)
3. Use `sortUsingDescriptors:`, and pass an array of at least one sort descriptor whose `ascending` property is false.

In the first two cases, your comparison should simply return the negation of what the comparator you normally use (e.g., `compare:`) returned. The last one involves less custom code, so it's what I'd use.

Answer (score 3):

I have a mutableArray and want to sort in descending order with "number" key. "number" key is a string like "12345", "12346". This way that I had tried and look very well. Hope help you!

```
NSComparisonResult result;

NSArray *arrTem = [multableArr sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    if([obj1 valueForKey:@"number"] > [obj2 valueForKey:@"number"])
         result = NSOrderedDescending;
    result = NSOrderedSame;
}];

return [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:arrTem];
```

Answer (score 2):

**For Example Data is Like this and we want to sort NSArray based on sId key.**

```
<__NSArrayM 0x7ffc725af1d0>(
{
    sId = 3;
    vName = ABC;
},
{
    sId = 10;
    vName = DEF;
},
{
    sId = 9;
    vName = GHI;
},
{
    sId = 7;
    vName = JKL;
},
{
    sId = 1;
    vName = MNO;
}
)
```

**Solution is as Below**

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [arrOptions sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    if ([[obj1 valueForKey:@"sId"] integerValue] > [[obj2 valueForKey:@"sId"] integerValue]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    if ([[obj1 valueForKey:@"sId"] integerValue] < [[obj2 valueForKey:@"sId"] integerValue]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];
NSLog(@"Sorted Service Array is ::%@",sortedArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

comare selector has to return NSComparisonResult. It's actually your function, so you can write another function, that returns the opposite result to sort in descending order.

Comment: Not necessarily. If the objects are instances of a built-in Cocoa class (such as NSString), you would have to category your custom comparison method onto the class.

Answer (score 1):

The [Dr. Touch](http://www.drobnik.com/touch/2010/01/array-self-sorting/) website has a nice implementation of a category on NSArray to create a self-sorting array. This could be modified to keep the sort in whatever order was appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

If you need based on ABCD in ascending then use following code

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor=[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"self" ascending:YES];
NSArray *descriptors=[NSArray arrayWithObject: descriptor];
NSArray *reverseOrder=[yourArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
```

Answer (score 0):

we can do it simply by using `sortUsingSelector`. The code as follows;

```
NSMutableArray *arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects: ..objects.. ];
//Can also use NSArray.
[arr sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:options:)];
NSString *temp;
int i,j;
i=0;
j=[arr count];
for(i=0;i<([arr count]-1);i++)
{
    temp=[arr objectAtIndex:i];
    [arr replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[arr objectAtIndex:j]];
    [arr replaceObjectAtIndex:j withObject:temp];
    j--;
}
NSLog(@"New array is:%@",arr);
```

You may think that WHAT A STUPID ANSWER it is :D :D Actually, am not teasing anyone. But in simple logic, we can sort array in descending order by this way. No need of using any type of `descriptors` or any other complicated stuffs. And it will be easier for entry level programmers.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code to sort Array on the basis of key on which you want to sort tge array (e.g name , code, address,emp_id etc...)

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Enter Sort Type" ascending:NO];

NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
return [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```