# How can i take NSArray Biggest Object

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsarray

i have a NSArray and  arrays are numbers like this;

```
NSArray *ratio = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"99",@"88",@"77", @"66", @"55", @"44",@"33", @"22",@"11",@"0",@"-11",@"-22",@"-33",@"-44",@"-55",@"-66",@"-77",@"-88",@"-99",@"-100",nil];
```

i want to take biggest object 99 and smallest object -100 hiw can i do this ?

i will use if condition biggest object like this ;

```
if ([[ratio objectAtIndex:i] intValue] == 100 ) {

            rd = 0;
            gr = 0.5;
            bl =0;
}
```

//i want to do this

```
if ([[ratio objectAtIndex:i] intValue] == biggestobject or smallestobject ) {
      ///.....
}
```

Help pls myfriends:( - Now solve problem but there is a another problem at follows.

Second one problem :(

```
NSSortDescriptor* sortOrder = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"self" ascending: NO];
NSLog(@"%@",[ratio sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject: sortOrder]]);
```

i sorted array but cannot choose biggest and smallest object from array. How can i do this?

NSLog screen is following like this; 99, 99, 99, 91, 91, 88, 88, 88, 88, 77, 77, 66, 66, 66,

how can i take objectforkey:0 at sorted array

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to just sort the array and take the first and last index.

[Sort an NSArray in Descending Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402667/sort-an-nsarray-in-descending-order)

Answer (score 1):

will this solve your issue:

```
NSInteger maxValue = 0, minValue = 0;
BOOL firstIteration = YES;

for(id item in ratio) {
    NSInteger intValue = [item integerValue];
    if( firstIteration ) {
        maxValue = intValue;
        minValue = intValue;
        firstIteration = NO;
        continue;
    }

    if( intValue < minValue ) minValue = intValue;

    if( intValue > maxValue ) maxValue = intValue;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Write this method to sort two strings as you have defined, note the `NSNumericSearch`  . [See Documentation here.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSNumericSearch)

```
NSComparisonResult sortNums(NSString *s1, NSString *s2, void *context) {    
        return [s2 compare:s1 options:NSNumericSearch];
    }
```

then sort using:

```
NSArray *sorted = [unsorted sortedArrayUsingFunction:sortNums context:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

to get the values, instead the following code:

```
NSSortDescriptor* sortOrder = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"self" ascending: NO];
NSLog(@"%@",[ratio sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject: sortOrder]]);
```

you need to use:

```
NSSortDescriptor* sortOrder = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"self" ascending: NO]; 
NSArray *sortedArray = [ratio sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject: sortOrder]];

NSLog(@"max item: %@, min item: %@", [soretedArray objectAtIndex:0], [sortedArray lastObject]);
```