# Sorted Array Select biggest and smallest object

Tags: objective-c, arrays, xcode

```
NSSortDescriptor* sortOrder = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"self" ascending: NO]; 
NSLog(@"%@",[ratio sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject: sortOrder]]);
```

i sorted array but cannot choose biggest and smallest object from array. How can i do this?

`NSLog` screen is following like this; `99, 99, 99, 91, 91, 88, 88, 88, 88, 77, 77, 66, 66, 66,`

how can i take `objectforkey:0` at sorted array

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i take NSArray Biggest Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876958/how-can-i-take-nsarray-biggest-object)

Answer (score 1):

have you tried `[array objectAtIndex:0]` and `[array lastObject]`? you should access an array's elements by their indexes, not `objectForKey:`.

```
id first = [array objectAtIndex:0];
id last = [array lastObject];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [ratio sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject: sortOrder]];
NSLog(@"Biggest : %@", [sortedArray objectAtIndex:0]);
NSLog(@"Smallest : %@", [sortedArray lastObject]);
```

Comment: i tried to code. but looks like 9,
    9,
    9,
    8,
    7,
    7,
    6,
    43,
    4,
    4,
    31,
    30,
    29,
    29,
    28,
    28,
    27,
    27,  i wantto descending objects :(