# How to sort numbers in NSArray?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, plist

I can't piece together how to do this.

I fetch my array from a plist, this array is full of numbers (as set in the plist). Now al I need to do is sort them so they are descending, but I can't work it out.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try this code?

```
 NSArray *array = /* loaded from file */;
 array = [array sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(compare:)];
```

Comment: But what would the contents of the selector method be? This is what gets me.

Comment: The `-compare:` method is defined for `NSNumber` instances: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumber/compare:

Comment: Thats the one I meant. Perhaps I misunderstanding the docs, but I have tried with and without the compare method and it always crashing the app saying unrecognised selector.

Comment: That's weird. Something must be up with your array then.

Comment: Hmm, its literally an arrays which looks like this: 1, 54, 23, 11, 8, 67. I'll look further into it.

Comment: It seems that (from your comment on the other answer) that you've populated your .plist with numbers *as strings* and not *as numbers*.

Comment: Am I the only one who finds this stupidly complicated? There's seriously no method for `NSArray` called `sortedArray` which calls exactly this? I love extensions and all, but why do I (and everyone else) have to write such basic stuff that Apple should have had in the standard libraries all along? Although Obj-C is a flawed language and Swift can't come quickly enough, it seems to me a bigger problem is the lousy libraries. I hope Swift's libraries don't leave me having to write out this basic stuff myself.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare: Since Arrays can hold any type of object, including entire subarrays and dictionaries, it's impossible to have a generic sorting routine that automatically knows how to sort your objects.  Let's say you have an array of UIViewControllers.  How should they be sorted?

Comment: @OwenHartnett - It should always use `compare:`. If the class you've inserted into your `NSArray` doesn't implement that method, then you shouldn't be using the `sortedArray` method. You'll have to fall back to the more flexible `sortedArrayUsingSelector:` method.

Comment: You can't always use compare: . In objective C, arrays can hold mixed types:  You might have a string, and NSNumber, a UIViewController and a NSDate all in the same array, yet there may be logical reason where a sort is appropriate.  Having a generic compare: as a default method could generate unattainable expectations and be very difficult to debug without checking the types of the array items.

Answer (score 16):

The following will sort the numbers in ascending order and then reverse the result to give the numbers in descending order:

```
NSArray *sorted = [[[array sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)] reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
```

This previous question has some other alternatives:
[Sort an NSArray in Descending Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402667/sort-an-nsarray-in-descending-order)

Comment: Im getting a crash with `-[__NSCFString sortedArrayUsingSelector:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`.

Comment: Are you sure you calling `sortedArrayUsingSelector:` on an `NSArray`?   You appear to be calling `sortedArrayUsingSelector:` on an `NSString`.  You should probably check the data structure that is being loaded from the Plist.

Comment: @Josh Kahane, if so, you are most likely having issues with memory management, because your `array` pointer points to `NSString` object. Forgot to retain / too much [auto]releases?

Comment: This answer fully answer's the question, as it sorts the array *descending*.

Answer (score 13):

Here is one of many methods using comparison block. This code snippet is handy for any array with numbers that you want to sort.
For Ascending order:

```
AscendingArray = [UnsortArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    if ([obj1 integerValue] > [obj2 integerValue]) {
      return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }

    if ([obj1 integerValue] < [obj2 integerValue]) {
      return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
  }];
```

For Descending order:

```
DescendingArray = [UnsortArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    if ([obj1 integerValue] > [obj2 integerValue]) {
      return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }

    if ([obj1 integerValue] < [obj2 integerValue]) {
      return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
  }];
```

Comment: why not just use NSNumber `compare:`?

Comment: I've used this method because even if some of my data are numbers, I've stored everything as string. This method can compare numbers that are stored as strings, contrary to compare: method

Answer (score 5):

It work for me:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortIdClient = 
[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"campaignValue"
                              ascending:NO
                             comparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2){

    return [obj1 compare:obj2 options:NSNumericSearch];

 }];

NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortIdClient];

NSArray *arrTemp = [self.allCampaignsList sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Answer (score 0):

This Will solve the problem:

```
 NSArray *array = /* loaded from file */;
 array = [array sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(compare:)];
```

Comment: please remove extra indentation which makes text be shown as code