# How to iterate for loop in reverse order in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

When I use the for loop in Playground, everything worked fine, until I changed the first parameter of for loop to be the highest value. (iterated in descending order)

Is this a bug? Did any one else have it?

```
for index in 510..509
{
    var a = 10
}
```

The counter that displays the number of iterations that will be executions keeps ticking...

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reverse Range in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24372559/reverse-range-in-swift)

Comment: Such a brilliant decision to drop c style loops. Bring them back

Comment: See [my answer with Swift 5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42467712/1966109) that shows up to 4 different ways to iterate in reverse order.

Comment: simply `.reversed()`, as in `for index in (509 ... 510).reversed() { ... }`

Answer (score 302, accepted):

Xcode 6 beta 4 added two functions to iterate on ranges with a step other than one:
`stride(from: to: by:)`, which is used with exclusive ranges and `stride(from: through: by:)`, which is used with inclusive ranges.

To iterate on a range in reverse order, they can be used as below:

```
for index in stride(from: 5, to: 1, by: -1) {
    print(index)
}
//prints 5, 4, 3, 2

for index in stride(from: 5, through: 1, by: -1) {
    print(index)
}
//prints 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```

Note that neither of those is a `Range` member function. They are global functions that return either a `StrideTo` or a `StrideThrough` struct, which are defined differently from the `Range` struct.

A previous version of this answer used the `by()` member function of the `Range` struct, which was removed in beta 4. If you want to see how that worked, check the edit history.

Comment: With Swift 2.0 it is now: `5.stride(to: 1, by: -1)` or `5.stride(through: 1, by: -1)`

Comment: With Swift 3.0 we're back to stride as a free function.

Comment: @Shaun it is a reasonable and safe choice. I can't tell you often R programmers are tripped by its `:` operator implicitly iterating downwards, causing their loops to execute when they thought it would skip over them. It's very convenient for interactive use, but terribly error prone in scripts, to the point where style guides [recommend against using it](https://jef.works/R-style-guide/#loops).

Answer (score 234):

Apply the reverse function to the range to iterate backwards:

For **Swift 1.2** and earlier:

```
// Print 10 through 1
for i in reverse(1...10) {
    println(i)
}
```

It also works with half-open ranges:

```
// Print 9 through 1
for i in reverse(1..<10) {
    println(i)
}
```

Note:  `reverse(1...10)` creates an array of type `[Int]`, so while this might be fine for small ranges, it would be wise to use `lazy` as shown below or consider the accepted `stride` answer if your range is large.

---

To avoid creating a large array, use `lazy` along with `reverse()`.  The following test runs efficiently in a Playground showing it is not creating an array with one trillion `Int`s!

**Test:**

```
var count = 0
for i in lazy(1...1_000_000_000_000).reverse() {
    if ++count > 5 {
        break
    }
    println(i)
}
```

---

For **Swift 2.0** in Xcode 7:

```
for i in (1...10).reverse() {
    print(i)
}
```

Note that in Swift 2.0, `(1...1_000_000_000_000).reverse()` is of type `ReverseRandomAccessCollection<(Range<Int>)>`, so this works fine:

```
var count = 0
for i in (1...1_000_000_000_000).reverse() {
    count += 1
    if count > 5 {
        break
    }
    print(i)
}
```

---

For **Swift 3.0** `reverse()` has been renamed to `reversed()`:

```
for i in (1...10).reversed() {
    print(i) // prints 10 through 1
}
```

Comment: `reversed` may copy the collection, though. At least, that's how I understand the documentation on `Data`.

Answer (score 132):

*Updated for Swift 3*

The answer below is a summary of the available options. Choose the one that best fits your needs.

## `reversed`: numbers in a range

**Forward**

```
for index in 0..<5 {
    print(index)
}

// 0
// 1
// 2
// 3
// 4
```

**Backward**

```
for index in (0..<5).reversed() {
    print(index)
}

// 4
// 3
// 2
// 1
// 0
```

## `reversed`: elements in `SequenceType`

```
let animals = ["horse", "cow", "camel", "sheep", "goat"]
```

**Forward**

```
for animal in animals {
    print(animal)
}

// horse
// cow
// camel
// sheep
// goat
```

**Backward**

```
for animal in animals.reversed() {
    print(animal)
}

// goat
// sheep
// camel
// cow
// horse
```

## `reversed`: elements with an index

Sometimes an index is needed when iterating through a collection. For that you can use `enumerate()`, which returns a tuple. The first element of the tuple is the index and the second element is the object.

```
let animals = ["horse", "cow", "camel", "sheep", "goat"]
```

**Forward**

```
for (index, animal) in animals.enumerated() {
    print("\(index), \(animal)")
}

// 0, horse
// 1, cow
// 2, camel
// 3, sheep
// 4, goat
```

**Backward**

```
for (index, animal) in animals.enumerated().reversed()  {
    print("\(index), \(animal)")
}

// 4, goat
// 3, sheep
// 2, camel
// 1, cow
// 0, horse
```

Note that as Ben Lachman noted in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37584823/3681880), you probably want to do `.enumerated().reversed()` rather than `.reversed().enumerated()` (which would make the index numbers increase).

## stride: numbers

Stride is way to iterate without using a range. There are two forms. The comments at the end of the code show what the range version would be (assuming the increment size is 1).

```
startIndex.stride(to: endIndex, by: incrementSize)      // startIndex..<endIndex
startIndex.stride(through: endIndex, by: incrementSize) // startIndex...endIndex
```

**Forward**

```
for index in stride(from: 0, to: 5, by: 1) {
    print(index)
}

// 0
// 1
// 2
// 3
// 4
```

**Backward**

Changing the increment size to `-1` allows you to go backward.

```
for index in stride(from: 4, through: 0, by: -1) {
    print(index)
}

// 4
// 3
// 2
// 1
// 0
```

Note the `to` and `through` difference.

## stride: elements of SequenceType

**Forward by increments of 2**

```
let animals = ["horse", "cow", "camel", "sheep", "goat"]
```

I'm using `2` in this example just to show another possibility.

```
for index in stride(from: 0, to: 5, by: 2) {
    print("\(index), \(animals[index])")
}

// 0, horse
// 2, camel
// 4, goat
```

**Backward**

```
for index in stride(from: 4, through: 0, by: -1) {
    print("\(index), \(animals[index])")
}

// 4, goat
// 3, sheep 
// 2, camel
// 1, cow  
// 0, horse
```

## Notes

- @matt has [an interesting solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35684734/3681880) where he defines his own reverse operator and calls it `>>>`. It doesn't take much code to define and is used like this:

  ```
  for index in 5>>>0 {
      print(index)
  }

  // 4
  // 3
  // 2
  // 1
  // 0
  ```
- Check out [On C-Style For Loops Removed from Swift 3](http://bjmiller.me/post/137624096422/on-c-style-for-loops-removed-from-swift-3)

Answer (score 53):

**Swift 4** onwards

```
for i in stride(from: 5, to: 0, by: -1) {
    print(i)
}
//prints 5, 4, 3, 2, 1

for i in stride(from: 5, through: 0, by: -1) {
    print(i)
}
//prints 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0
```

Answer (score 49):

With Swift 5, according to your needs, you may choose one of the **four following Playground code examples** in order to solve your problem.

---

## #1. Using `ClosedRange` `reversed()` method

`ClosedRange` has a method called [`reversed()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/closedrange/2995047-reversed). `reversed()` method has the following declaration:

```
func reversed() -> ReversedCollection<ClosedRange<Bound>>
```

> Returns a view presenting the elements of the collection in reverse order.

*Usage:*

```
let reversedCollection = (0 ... 5).reversed()

for index in reversedCollection {
    print(index)
}

/*
Prints:
5
4
3
2
1
0
*/
```

As an alternative, you can use `Range` [`reversed()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/range/2996665-reversed) method:

```
let reversedCollection = (0 ..< 6).reversed()

for index in reversedCollection {
    print(index)
}

/*
Prints:
5
4
3
2
1
0
*/
```

---

## #2. Using `sequence(first:next:)` function

Swift Standard Library provides a function called [`sequence(first:next:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2015879-sequence). `sequence(first:next:)` has the following declaration:

```
func sequence<T>(first: T, next: @escaping (T) -> T?) -> UnfoldFirstSequence<T>
```

> Returns a sequence formed from `first` and repeated lazy applications of `next`.

*Usage:*

```
let unfoldSequence = sequence(first: 5, next: {
    $0 > 0 ? $0 - 1 : nil
})

for index in unfoldSequence {
    print(index)
}

/*
Prints:
5
4
3
2
1
0
*/
```

---

## #3. Using `stride(from:through:by:)` function

Swift Standard Library provides a function called [`stride(from:through:by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1641185-stride). `stride(from:through:by:)` has the following declaration:

```
func stride<T>(from start: T, through end: T, by stride: T.Stride) -> StrideThrough<T> where T : Strideable
```

> Returns a sequence from a starting value toward, and possibly including, an end value, stepping by the specified amount.

*Usage:*

```
let sequence = stride(from: 5, through: 0, by: -1)

for index in sequence {
    print(index)
}

/*
Prints:
5
4
3
2
1
0
*/
```

As an alternative,  you can use [`stride(from:to:by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1641347-stride):

```
let sequence = stride(from: 5, to: -1, by: -1)

for index in sequence {
    print(index)
}

/*
Prints:
5
4
3
2
1
0
*/
```

---

## #4. Using `AnyIterator` `init(_:)` initializer

`AnyIterator` has an initializer called [`init(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/anyiterator/1784409-init). `init(_:)` has the following declaration:

```
init(_ body: @escaping () -> AnyIterator<Element>.Element?)
```

> Creates an iterator that wraps the given closure in its `next()` method.

*Usage:*

```
var index = 5

guard index >= 0 else { fatalError("index must be positive or equal to zero") }

let iterator = AnyIterator({ () -> Int? in
    defer { index = index - 1 }
    return index >= 0 ? index : nil
})

for index in iterator {
    print(index)
}

/*
Prints:
5
4
3
2
1
0
*/
```

If needed, you can refactor the previous code by creating an extension method for `Int` and wrapping your iterator in it:

```
extension Int {

    func iterateDownTo(_ endIndex: Int) -> AnyIterator<Int> {
        var index = self
        guard index >= endIndex else { fatalError("self must be greater than or equal to endIndex") }

        let iterator = AnyIterator { () -> Int? in
            defer { index = index - 1 }
            return index >= endIndex ? index : nil
        }
        return iterator
    }

}

let iterator = 5.iterateDownTo(0)

for index in iterator {
    print(index)
}

/*
Prints:
5
4
3
2
1
0
*/
```

Comment: sequence(first: 5, next: { ($0 > 0) ? ($0 - 1) : nil }) // is simpler than ($0 - 1 >= 0)

Answer (score 29):

For Swift 2.0 and above you should apply reverse on a range collection

```
for i in (0 ..< 10).reverse() {
  // process
}
```

It has been renamed to .reversed() in Swift 3.0

Answer (score 9):

**In Swift 4 and latter**

```
    let count = 50//For example
    for i in (1...count).reversed() {
        print(i)
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 4.0**

```
for i in stride(from: 5, to: 0, by: -1) {
    print(i) // 5,4,3,2,1
}
```

If you want to include the `to` value:

```
for i in stride(from: 5, through: 0, by: -1) {
    print(i) // 5,4,3,2,1,0
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If one is wanting to iterate through an *array* (`Array` or more generally any `SequenceType`) in reverse. You have a few additional options.

First you can `reverse()` the array and loop through it as normal. However I prefer to use `enumerate()` much of the time since it outputs a tuple containing the object and it's index.

The one thing to note here is that it is important to call these in the right order:

`for (index, element) in array.enumerate().reverse()`

yields indexes in descending order (which is what I generally expect). whereas:

`for (index, element) in array.reverse().enumerate()` (which is a closer match to NSArray's `reverseEnumerator`)

walks the array backward but outputs ascending indexes.

Answer (score 3):

**as for Swift 2.2 , Xcode 7.3 (10,June,2016) :**

```
for (index,number) in (0...10).enumerate() {
    print("index \(index) , number \(number)")
}

for (index,number) in (0...10).reverse().enumerate() {
    print("index \(index) , number \(number)")
}
```

**Output :**

```
index 0 , number 0
index 1 , number 1
index 2 , number 2
index 3 , number 3
index 4 , number 4
index 5 , number 5
index 6 , number 6
index 7 , number 7
index 8 , number 8
index 9 , number 9
index 10 , number 10


index 0 , number 10
index 1 , number 9
index 2 , number 8
index 3 , number 7
index 4 , number 6
index 5 , number 5
index 6 , number 4
index 7 , number 3
index 8 , number 2
index 9 , number 1
index 10 , number 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can consider using the C-Style `while` loop instead. This works just fine in Swift 3:

```
var i = 5 
while i > 0 { 
    print(i)
    i -= 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This will works decrement by one in reverse order.

```
let num1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
for item in nums1.enumerated().reversed() { 

    print(item.offset) // Print the index number: 4,3,2,1,0
    print(item.element) // Print the value :5,4,3,2,1

}
```

Or you can use this index, value property

```
let num1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
for (index,item) in nums1.enumerated().reversed() { 

    print(index) // Print the index number: 4,3,2,1,0
    print(item) // Print the value :5,4,3,2,1

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var sum1 = 0
for i in 0...100{
    sum1 += i
}
print (sum1)

for i in (10...100).reverse(){
    sum1 /= i
}
print(sum1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reversed() method for easily reverse values.

```
var i:Int
for i in 1..10.reversed() {
    print(i)
}
```

The reversed() method reverse the values.

Answer (score 1):

Reversing an array can be done with just single step **.reverse()**

```
var arrOfnum = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
arrOfnum.reverse()
```

Answer (score -3):

> For me, this is the best way.

```
var arrayOfNums = [1,4,5,68,9,10]

for i in 0..<arrayOfNums.count {
    print(arrayOfNums[arrayOfNums.count - i - 1])
}
```

Comment: The best native way