# Removing objects from NSMutableArray that are also contained in another NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have two `array`, called `array1` and `array2`. I would like to remove every object from `array1` that's value of the `"nameId"` key can be find in both array. Actually I'm trying it in a `for loop`, but it doesn't make sense. It doesn not crash, it just simply calls the log in the `else statement`, that I don't understand why happens. Maybe somebody could show me the right solution.

```
NSMutableArray *newArray = [self.array1 mutableCopy];

for (PFObject * object in newArray) {

    PFObject *placeholderObject = object;

    for (PFObject *object2 in self.array2) {

        if ([placeholderObject[@"nameId"] isEqualToString:object2[@"nameId"]]) {

            [self.array1 removeObject:object];

            NSLog (@"EXISTING OBJECT FOUND %@", object);
        } else {


            NSLog(@"UNIQUE OBJECT FOUND %@", idO[@"hirCime"]);

        }


    }


}
```

Comment: if `array1` and `array2` are immutable arrays, shouldn't you should be doing "`[newArray removeObject:object]`"?  Also, did you step through this via the Xcode debugger to see if there is a case where placeHolderObject's "`nameId`" is equal to the what's in object2 ?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann It isn't a good idea to remove items from arrays in the body of fast enumeration loops - it will likely trigger "NSArray was mutated while being enumerated" exceptions. OP should definitely check that `if` statement though.

Comment: yeah, you're right about removing items from arrays like that.  I usually use [reverse enumeration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24508592/how-to-iterate-for-loop-in-reverse-order-in-swift) in cases where I'm removing items from a mutable array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove objects from array based on other array's object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32741424/how-to-remove-objects-from-array-based-on-other-arrays-object)

Answer (score 0):

When creating a mutableCopy of an array you create a new array with a copy of every object in it but they aren't the same ones, so `object` is a member of `newArray` but is not a member of `self.array1` so you can't remove it from that array.

This should work:

```
// Creates a new empty mutable array
NSMutableArray *newArray = [@[] mutableCopy]; 

for (PFObject *object in self.array) {

    BOOL found = NO;

    for (PFObject *object2 in self.array2) {

        if ([object[@"nameId"] isEqualToString:object2[@"nameId"]]) {
            found = YES;
            NSLog (@"EXISTING OBJECT FOUND %@", object);
            break;

        } else {
            NSLog(@"UNIQUE OBJECT FOUND %@", idO[@"hirCime"]);
        }
    }

    if (!found) {
        [newArray addObject:[object copy]];
    }
}

// And maybe you want this 
self.array = newArray;
```