# Loop Through An Array Backwards (Swift)

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm trying to loop through one of my arrays in reverse order... Is there a way to do this? Here is my script in normal order:

```
    for post in objects{
    //CODE
```

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish this with objects, not strings or numbers... If that is what I need, would you mind customizing it to my request? Thank you :)

Comment: You're asking about accessing an array in reverse order. The answer is in the linked page: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24886662/2227743

Comment: There we go, that was the answer I needed. Thanks

Comment: "I'm trying to accomplish this with objects, not strings or numbers" Strings and numbers _are_ objects.