# Decrementing For() loop

Tags: for-loop, swift3

What is the syntax of a decrementing for() loop?

I would like to do something like the following without getting a compilation error:

```
for ndx in 5...4 {
    print("do something")
}
```

Comment: Do make sure to jump down to the highest-rated (but not accepted) answer. In your example: `for ndx in (4...5).reversed() {`

Comment: I found another soln via stride() at: [stride](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24508592/how-to-iterate-for-loop-in-reverse-order-in-swift)

Answer (score 7):

This prints the value of i in reverse order:

```
for i in (1...10).reversed() {
print(i)
}
```