# Swift range operator for i = mymax; i >= 0 i--

Tags: swift, for-loop, swift3

I facing problem in executing for loop in Swift 3. I can use loop for range operator  `...`  and `..<` but in may case, I want something like `..>` but its not available.

How do I execute following loop in Swift 3?

```
var myMax = 20
for var i = myMax ; i >= 0 ; i -= 1 {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to reverse the loop. User `reversed` function.

**Swift 3**

```
let myMax = 20
for i in (1..<myMax).reversed() {
    print(i)
}
```

You can also use `stride` as @ZaidPathan said :

This question have all answers with all versions : [How to iterate for loop in reverse order in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24508592/how-to-iterate-for-loop-in-reverse-order-in-swift)

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in (1..<20).reversed() {
    print(i)
}
```

Hope it helps.[Read More](https://www.natashatherobot.com/swift-alternatives-to-c-style-for-loops/)

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3**, You can use `stride`

```
var myMax = 20
for var i = myMax ; i > 0 ; i -= 1 {

}

//Equivalent

let myMax = 20
for value in stride(from: 20, to: 0, by: -1){
    print(value)
}
```

```
var myMax = 20
for var i = myMax ; i >= 0 ; i -= 1 {

}

//Equivalent

for value in stride(from: 20, through: 0, by: -1){
    print(value)
}
```