# how can I reverse the for( ) loop in xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm trying to reverse a for loop in xcode.

```
for (enemyBullet *b in bullets)
{

}
```

can someone help ?

thanks

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586370/how-can-i-reverse-a-nsarray-in-objective-c

Comment: enemyBullet should be EnemyBullet.

Answer (score 6):

Perspx's way will not utilize fast object enumeration.  What you really want to do is:

> ```
> NSEnumerator *bulletReverseObjectEnumerator = [bullets reverseObjectEnumerator];
> for (enemyBullet *b in bulletReverseObjectEnumerator) {
>    NSLog(@"DANCE BULLET DANCE: %@", b);
> }
> ```

Concept being, fast object enumeration is several times faster than iterating with a flat while-loop.

Answer (score 5):

```
NSEnumerator *enu = [bullets reverseObjectEnumerator];

enemyBullet *b = nil;

while (b = [enu nextObject]) {
    // do your stuff here
}
```