# How do I reverse the order of objects in an NSMutableArray?

Tags: cocoa, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to achieve something like this

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C", nil];
NSLog(@"Array: %@", myArray);
//logs A, B, C.

//reverse code here

 NSLog(@"Array: %@", myArray);
//logs C, B, A
```

The code isn't exact, just a demo. But you get the idea.

Any way to do this?

Comment: I found this similar post on stackOverflow:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586370/how-can-i-reverse-a-nsarray-in-objective-c I think it will fit your requirements as well.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Simply use;

```
NSArray* reversed = [[myArray reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
```

The order [is documented](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSEnumerator_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSEnumerator/allObjects) to be correct:

> This array contains all the remaining objects of the enumerator **in enumerated order** [emphasis added].

Comment: will this work with mutable array?

Comment: Yes;  an NSMutableArray is, by declaration, a subclass of NSArray.

Comment: Not guaranteed to work. It could break anytime.

Comment: @user102008 The allObjects call made at the end is not *guaranteed* to return objects in any defined order.  It just happens to always return them in order on devices so far.

Comment: @GeorgSchölly Now guaranteed by documentation.