# Is it possible to convert NSMutableArray into its reverse order in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, reverse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I reverse a NSArray in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586370/how-can-i-reverse-a-nsarray-in-objective-c)

I've `NSMutableArray *mutArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:obj1,obj2,obj3,nil];`
and each object have name, title, address 
but i want to show mutArray in another NSMutableArray which shows in reverse order it means
obj3, obj2 & then obj1 , nil 
how i do it.

Comment: Already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586370/how-can-i-reverse-a-nsarray-in-objective-c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this on this way:

```
NSMutableArray* reversedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray: mutArray] reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the following and it worked for me:

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                 initWithKey:@"key"  ascending:YES];

[mutableArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]];
```

`mutableArray = [mutableArray copy];`

```
[descriptor release];
```

Hope it helps!