# How to display an array in reverse order in objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to display data in UITableView in reverse order.
I manage to do it with little effort but can any one provide a better way to do it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: To think of a method better then yours it would be great what your method is...

Comment: I recommend updating your question with your attempt, otherwise you're unlikely to get much of a response.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well i dont know what your code is but you can do something like this

```
cell.title = [anarray objectAtIndex:(anarray.count - indexPath.row - 1)];
```

Hope this may works.
Cheers.

Comment: Fixed formatting and changed an erroneous set of `[`...`]` to `(`...`)`

Answer (score 31):

Use [`-[NSArray reverseObjectEnumerator]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BABECCHA):

```
NSArray * a = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a", @"b", @"c", nil];
NSArray * reverse = [[a reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
NSLog(@"%@", reverse);  //logs "c, b, a"
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a much easier solution, if you take advantage of the built-in reverseObjectEnumerator method on NSArray, and the allObjects method of NSEnumerator:

```
NSArray* reversedArray = [[startArray reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
```

Comment: That *is* a pretty good solution, but I notice that Dave DeLong suggested the same thing 2.5 years ago. Did you miss his answer?

Comment: Its also an exact copy and paste of this answer by somebody else from almost 4 years ago here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/586529/1026573