# How to reverse the data in NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4, nsmutablearray

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to display an array in reverse order in objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644755/how-to-display-an-array-in-reverse-order-in-objective-c)

I have an `NSMutableArray` and this array contains information nicely in `UITableView`.
but I want to display latest information first in `UITableView`. Right now the earliest information comes first in `UITableView`. My code is as follows:

```
NSMutableArray *entries = [NSMutableArray array];
[self parseFeed:doc.rootElement entries:entries];
for (RSSEntry *entry in entries) {
    [allEntries insertObject:entry atIndex:0];   //insertIdx];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
}
```

then How can I reverse the information in `NSMutableArray`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about just enumerating the contents of `entries` in reverse order?

```
for (RSSEntry *entry in [entries reverseObjectEnumerator]) {
    ...
}
```

If you just want to take an array and create a reversed array, you can do this:

```
NSArray *reversedEntries = [[entries reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
```

Comment: Of course if you really need an array reversed from the original, just fill a second mutable array while reverse enumerating.

Answer (score 7):

You can try like this way:

```
for (int k = [originalArray count] - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
    [reverseArray addObject:[originalArray objectAtIndex:k]];
}
```

Comment: only solution I found that works for nsmutablearray.  Thanks!