# "Reverse" NSMutableArray's elements order

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I reverse a NSArray in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586370/how-can-i-reverse-a-nsarray-in-objective-c)

Is there a way to reverse the elements in a NSMutableArray?

Comment: Have you searched this site, or even taken a look at the suggestions made to you as you entered the title of your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How can I reverse a NSArray in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586370/how-can-i-reverse-a-nsarray-in-objective-c)

Comment: Particularly: http://stackoverflow.com/a/586529/999934

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that there is an easy way to do it.  Best way that I came up with is the exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObjectAtIndex: function.

pseudo code:

```
NSMutableArray* array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3",nil];
for(i = 0, len = (int)[array count]/2; i < len; i++)
{
  [array exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:([array count] - i - 1)];
}
```

Don't have the compiler open right at this moment but hopefully this does the trick.