# Reversing elements in an array in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray

Is there something I'm missing with NSUInteger.  I originally wanted to do this in my .m file.  (I saw some code about using an NSEnumerator, but I didn't quite understand it so I thought for my needs, this would be sufficient).

So I wanted to do this:

```
- (NSArray *)reverseArray:(NSMutableArray *)array {
    NSMutableArray *anArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[array count]];
    for (NSUInteger i = [array count] - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        [anArray addObject:[array objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    return anArray;
}
```

This gives me the compiler warning that i >= 0 is what NSUInteger is designed to do or something along those lines.  When I run the program, it also crashes and accesses some super huge number.  I'm not quite sure why.  I can offset i by 1 everywhere and do this, and this works:

```
- (NSArray *)reverseArray:(NSMutableArray *)array {
    NSMutableArray *anArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[array count]];
    for (NSUInteger i = [array count]; (i) ; i--) {
        [anArray addObject:[array objectAtIndex:i - 1]];
    }
    return anArray;
}
```

I just didn't understand why the first method does not work.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Here's a nice self-contained macro for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51342529/2057171

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSUInteger` is an `unsigned` integer. So, if `NSUInteger u=0` and if you calculate `u-1`, it doesn't become `-1`. Instead, it underflows and it becomes a super huge number.

Changing your code to

```
 for (NSInteger i = [array count] - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
```

should solve the problem.

Note that you don't really have to reverse the array. The for-loop

```
for(a in array){
    ... do something with a ...
}
```

enumerates elements in the forward order, and

```
for(a in [array reverseObjectEnumerator]){
    ... do something with a ...
}
```

enumerates elements in the reverse order.

Answer (score 1):

An unsigned integer is always >= 0.  So your first loop will never terminate, which eventually results in it trying to access the `objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)-1`, which is actually a very large positive index, causing the crash.

Fortunately, you seem to have figured out how to fix the problem already.  Good work.

Note that there is nothing specific to Objective-C about this; programmers commonly make the same mistake with unsigned integers in basically every suitably low-level language.

Answer (score 0):

NSUInteger is "unsigned", meaning it can't have the - sign denoting a negative number.
In your code...

```
NSUInteger i = [array count] - 1; i >= 0 ; i--
```

That will eventually equal -1, hence the error.
Try removing = for something like this.

```
NSUInteger i = [array count] - 1; i > 0 ; i--
```