# Changing the sort order of -[NSArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:]

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sorting, nsarray

I need to generate a sorted array of `NSNumber`s from another `NSArray`. I want to use the `sortedArrayUsingComparator:` method. I found this example in the Apple documentation:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    if ([obj1 integerValue] > [obj2 integerValue]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }

    if ([obj1 integerValue] < [obj2 integerValue]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }

    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

Here I am just providing the comparator in a block, which is fine. The sort itself -- the bit that's hidden from me, which uses this block -- appears to be ascending.

I'd like to know if I can request a different sort order external to this block, or do I just need to flip the `<` and `>`'s (or `NSOrderedXXX`'s) around?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you want to sort descending, then just flip the comparisons (or flip the `NSComparisonResult`s). There's no need to bloat the API by having an `ascending:` parameter when you can control that in the block directly.

Answer (score 5):

Just change the logic:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {

 if ([obj1 integerValue] > [obj2 integerValue]) {
      return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
 }

 if ([obj1 integerValue] < [obj2 integerValue]) {
      return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
 }
 return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

For clarity it might be best to make this a method with a name similar to: `decendingSort`.

Comment: Of course this is fine, but unless you decorate it with orange-traffic-cone comments written in red-Jesus-Christ-ink stating that you've flipped the order around, at some point later this could be a potential debugging nightmare.

Building a sort descriptor would make more sense and be self-commenting unless the performance would take a serious hit.

Comment: @God A sort descriptor sounds great, please provide an implementation example for comparison.

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation for `-sortedArrayUsingComparator:` :

"Returns an array that lists the receiving array’s elements in ascending order, as determined by the comparison method specified by a given NSComparator Block."

So You'd have to resort to using

```
- (NSArray *)sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:(NSArray *)sortDescriptors
```

but of course that means rolling your own NSSortDescriptor objects first, which may suit your purposes just fine.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that this is, in fact, documented. Cheers Jeff.

Answer (score 4):

**You can flip the operators around.**

The "bit that's hidden from you" doesn't care about ascending or descending, as it doesn't know anything about your objects. It's like asking your co-worker if a hockey puck is greater or less than a muskrat. The internal implementation just uses a sorting algorithm (which is probably determined using the size of your array) and uses your block function to compare two objects.

Answer (score 4):

As a side note, you are able to get the reversed order of an array using this

`[[NSArray reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];`

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/586529/1382210