# Integer From Input To English

Tags: objective-c, xcode, command-line

What I'm trying to do is have the user input a number, and then the program reads each digit back in word form. For example:

```
Input: 517

Output: Five One Seven
```

It's a simple command-line tool, using NSLogs and scanf to get the input and provide output, nothing too advanced. I have the jist of it, but it only works with one-digit numbers:

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {

        int number;

        NSLog(@"Type your number.");
        scanf("%i", &number);


        if (number == 0) {
            NSLog(@"Zero");
        } else if (number == 1){
            NSLog(@"One");
        } else if (number == 2) {
            NSLog(@"Two");
        } else if (number == 3) {
            NSLog(@"Three"); 
        } else if (number == 4) {
            NSLog(@"Four");
        } else if (number == 5) {
            NSLog(@"Five");
        } else if (number == 6) {
            NSLog(@"Six");
        } else if (number == 7) {
            NSLog(@"Seven");
        } else  if (number == 8) {
            NSLog(@"Eight");
        } else if (number == 9) {
            NSLog(@"Nine");
        } 

    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, I'm having problems working with more digits. I was thinking of using something like this to split them up:

```
            right_digit = number % 10;
        NSLog(@"%i", right_digit);
        number /= 10;
```

But that would output backwards.

Any advice?

Thanks

Comment: No, I'm going through a textbook on my own, trying to pick up on the Objective-C language more so than the applications in an  iOS app

Comment: An interesting tool that does more than this: 
 https://helloacm.com/tools/convert-arabic-numerals-to-english-words/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Recursion

```
void printNumber(int a){
  if(a/10 > 0){
     printNumber(a/10);
  }

  int digit = a%10;
  switch(digit){
  {
    case 0:
       NSLog(@"Zero ");
       break;
    case 1:
       NSLog(@"One ");
       break;
    case 2:
       NSLog("Two ");
       break;
     ....
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you create a list backwards then reverse it, and read the number to the user.

The user won't see any difference in terms of performance.

To do this with an array you can look at this question:

[How can I reverse a NSArray in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586370/how-can-i-reverse-a-nsarray-in-objective-c)

Comment: I am able to get it to print the numbers.. but backwards.

Comment: Reverse the array, then read the numbers from index 0 to the end.

Answer (score 0):

`NSNumberFormatter` has a styler that helps handle it for you.

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NumberFormatter alloc] init];
numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle;
```