# iPhone-Sorting Array

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I want to sort my array....
In my array elements are in this order    dateArray{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19}

But i want this array in reverse order
I used this code for reversing..

```
dateArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[[date reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects]];
```

But it gives this output

```
dateArray=(
9,
8,
7,
6,
5,
4,
3,
2,
19,
18,
17,
16,
15,
14,
13,
12,
11,
10,
1,
0
)
```

But i want this output dateArray(19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10........2,1,0)
I also used sorting method but output is same. how can i do this??? Please help

EDITED:

My array elements are the contents of NSDocument Directory....

SOLVED
 this question has been sovled. I don't know the exact way to sort my array as i want but i changed my subpaths name. and it gives right output..

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It seems to be sorting based on `NSString` not `NSNumber`. I would suggest you use something like `sortUsingComparator:`.

Comment: if you are want to work with strings instead of numbers, you should use the following format for the correct sorting: `20`, `19`, ... `10`, `09`, `08`, ... `02`, `01`, `00`, therefore, you just have to add a leading `0` to every number.

Comment: @holex actually i m fetching element from document directory. elements are the subpaths of directory. I can't rename in 00,01,02.

Comment: @Rox,if they are strings, you can sort them like strings, not numbers... by the way in that case rename the subpaths then. who designed the application's architecture?

Comment: and then how to sort them as string???

Comment: @holex Thanx holex i followed ur advice and rename the subpaths. now i gives that output which i want, thanks 4 that.....

Comment: @holex yes, sure why not... make answer. I'll accept it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are want to work with strings instead of numbers, you should use the following format for the correct sorting:

`20`, `19`, ... `10`, `09`, `08`, ... `02`, `01`, `00`

therefore, you just have to add a leading `0` to every number. if they are strings, you can sort them like strings only, not like numbers, this is why the leading zero is needed.

---

by the way the most painless solution is **to rename the subpaths** then, where the strings come, and you won't need to change anything else in your application for getting the right order.

Answer (score 2):

I assuming that your array contained objects and not numbers as in your question. Here's an example to sort an array in ascending or descending order.

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]  initWithObjects:@"5",@"1",@"0",@"3",@"2",@"4", nil];

//or

NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5], [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:3], [NSNumber numberWithInt:2], [NSNumber numberWithInt:4], nil];


NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:nil ascending:NO]; //YES, for ascending
NSLog(@"Sorted array %@",[array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sort, nil]]);
```

Comment: @Rox, see this edited data! It works for me! Let me know whats the type of your data, are they objects (strings) or of type number?

Comment: It is sorting your elements but if ur elements from 1 to 20 then it gives this output dateArray=(9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,1,0)... but i want in series like (20,19,.... 2,1,0)

Comment: @Rox, It's working for number as well. Don't know why its not suit your need! In which format its returning from NSDocumentDirectory. If its in NSDictionary, you need to pass `key` of that field in `NSSortDescriptor`.

Comment: BTW [NSNumber numberWithInt:1]; is the same as @1;

Comment: NSArray *date = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:dateDir  error:nil];       I am using this code for retrieving elements of directory and storing in NSArray

Answer (score 1):

you need to use

```
-[NSArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:]
```

or

`-[NSMutableArray sortUsingSelector:]` and pass @selector(compare:) as the parameter.

Comment: ahh, i didn't get. Plz explain how to do??

Answer (score 1):

Three ways (of many others, I am sure).
Easiest way ([thanks to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586370/how-can-i-reverse-a-nsarray-in-objective-c)), is to use the reverseObjectEnumerator:

```
NSArray *dateArrayReversed = [[dateArray reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
```

Or you could use a sort descriptor (messy):

```
NSArray *arrayOne = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@1,@2,@3,@4,@5,@6,@7,@8,@9,@10,@11,@12,@13,@14,@15,@16,@17,@18,@19, nil];

NSSortDescriptor* sortOrder = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"self" ascending: NO];
    NSArray *arrayTwo =  [arrayOne sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject: sortOrder]];
```

The other way is to create a category for the reversed array.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586370/how-can-i-reverse-a-nsarray-in-objective-c) 
SO question for a great example of that.

[How can I reverse a NSArray in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586370/how-can-i-reverse-a-nsarray-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done, you can sort your array via NSSortDescriptor but there is a little trick that I will show to you.Here is the code

```
NSMutableArray *yourArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"5",@"10",@"6",@"3",@"11", nil];

NSMutableArray *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
int count=[yourArray count];
for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
    [array addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[yourArray objectAtIndex:i]intValue]],@"val", nil]];
}

if([array count] > 0){
    NSSortDescriptor * descriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"val"
                                                                 ascending:NO] autorelease];
    NSArray * sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
                             [NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor]];
    [array removeAllObjects];
    [array addObjectsFromArray:sortedArray];
}
[yourArray removeAllObjects];
[yourArray release];
NSLog(@"sorted array=%@",array);
```

What I am doing in this is that first add your string objects in NSNumber form on a mutable dictionary then add this dictionary into another array.Now use NSSortDescriptor to sort the array in either order ascending or descending.