# Sorting an NSDictionary, descending. How do I send options with the `compare:options:` selector?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I am attempting to sort an NSDictionary.

From the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Dictionaries.html)  I see you can use `keysSortedByValueUsingSelector`:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:63], @"Mathematics",
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:72], @"English",
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:55], @"History",
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:49], @"Geography",
    nil];

NSArray *sortedKeysArray = [dict keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

which gives:

```
// sortedKeysArray contains: Geography, History, Mathematics, English
```

but I want:

```
// sortedKeysArray contains: English, Mathematics, History, Geography
```

I have read that you can use `compare:options:`, and an `NSStringCompareOptions` to change the comparison to compare in the other direction.

However I don't understand how you send `compare:options:` *with an option* in the selector.

I want to do something like this:

```
NSArray *sortedKeysArray = [dict keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:@selector(compare:options:NSOrderDescending)];
```

How should I switch the order of the comparison?

Related:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3411089?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: `NSArray *ascedingArray=[[sortedKeysArray reverseObjectEnumerator]allObjects];`

Answer (score 13):

**Option 1:** Use a comparator to invoke `-compare:` in reverse: (Thanks Dan Shelly!)

```
NSArray *blockSortedKeys = [dict keysSortedByValueUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {
     // Switching the order of the operands reverses the sort direction
     return [objc2 compare:obj1];
}];
```

Just reverse the descending and ascending return statements and you should get just what you want.

**Option 2:** Reverse the array you have:

See [How can I reverse a NSArray in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/586370/893113)

Comment: or [dict keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
            return [obj2 compare:obj1];
        }];

Comment: That wouldn't reverse the array, though maybe `return -[objc2 compare:obj1]` would work.

Comment: I've tested it on a simple example ..., To be more specific, in a comparison based sort, reversing the order of comparison will reverse the resulting array

Answer (score 4):

I use :

```
    NSSortDescriptor *sortOrder = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"self" ascending:NO];
    self. sortedKeys = [[self.keyedInventoryItems allKeys] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortOrder]];
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  It sorts the keys in descending order, without reference to the values in the dictionary. @noa's answer to use the comparator is correct.