# how to iterate an array in reverse order after it encounter last element?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

How to put condition for an array to display the images. if it encounters last element of array it should go to previous order i.e., consider array have some 5 elements. 0 1 2 3 4 i need to traverse from 0 1 2 3 4 after encounter 5th object now to it should traverse to 4 3 2 1 0. How to put this logic?

Comment: Possible duplicated of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586370/how-can-i-reverse-a-nsarray-in-objective-c

Comment: r u trying for animation?

Comment: Can you provide more information on what you are trying to achieve.  Do you want to reverse direction again when reach the first element?

Answer (score 0):

I just put my logic

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < myArray.count; i ++)
{
  NSLog(@"%d", i);
  if(i == myArray.count -1)
  {
    for(int j = myArray.count-1 ; j >= 0; j --)
    {
       NSLog(@"%d", j);
    }
  }
}
```

Try with it, its working well. :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is doing 2 loops.

```
for (NSInteger i = 0;i < [array count]; i++)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [array objectAtIndex:i]);
}

for (NSInteger i = [array count] - 1;i >= 0; i--)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [array objectAtIndex:i]);
}
```