# iOS Custom Keyboard Extension Full Context in Field

Tags: ios, swift, swift-extensions, swift-keyboard

Currently, I am working on a custom Swift keyboard and using the Keyboard Kit framework.

I have researched various solutions, and [this one is the best](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37956477/13989286)

But after I implemented this code for Swift 5, it works when I placed cursor end of the text.

Code:

```
    let readerQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.customKeyboard.reader.test")
    
    func foo() {
        readerQueue.async {
            self.keyboardService.fullDocumentContext()
        }
    }

    func fullDocumentContext() {
        guard let textProxy else { return }
        var startingOffset = 0
        var context = ""
        
        while let previeosContext = textProxy.documentContextBeforeInput, !previeosContext.isEmpty {
            context = previeosContext + context
            startingOffset += previeosContext.count
            textProxy.adjustTextPosition(byCharacterOffset: -previeosContext.count)
            Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.01)
        }
        
        textProxy.adjustTextPosition(byCharacterOffset: context.count)
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.01)
        
        while let nextContext = textProxy.documentContextAfterInput, !nextContext.isEmpty {
            context += nextContext
            textProxy.adjustTextPosition(byCharacterOffset: nextContext.count)
            Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.01)
        }
        
        print(context)
    }
```

If I place the cursor in the middle of the text and retrieve data from before the cursor, then move the cursor back and try to iterate forward, it only works once. I do not figure it out why it can not iterate forward.