# How to sort UIImage added NSMutableArray in ios in descending

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, nsarray

I am working for UIImage storing to NSMutableArray. How i can sort it with the UIImage because it's not storing any parameter or for-key by which i can sort using any comparator code.

I am working to store UIImage from image picker controller. After storing numbers of images to NSMutableArray. After that i need to sort My mutable to Last In First out(LIFO). It's currently working as First In First Out(FIFO) or descending. We are storing images to array as follow:

```
NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[info count]];

    for (NSDictionary *dict in info) {

        UIImage *image = [dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        [images addObject:image];

    }


    [_currentData addObjectsFromArray:images];
```

After Storing i am not able to Sort Last added object to First display in image view.
Following code Crashes for me:

```
NSSortDescriptor *desc = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"" ascending:NO];
    [_currentData sortUsingDescriptors:@[desc]];
```

My _currentData is main NSMutableArray which i am using to display in the table view after shorting.

Please help me For sorting UIImage stored NSMutableArray for LAST IN FIRST OUT(LIFO) descending order.

Comment: The word is 'sort', not 'short.'

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I reverse a NSArray in Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586370/how-can-i-reverse-a-nsarray-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution is fetch data using reverse for loop.

```
for (int i = arr.count-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    UIImage *img = [arr objectAtIndex:i];
}
```

get images from your NSMutableArray using reverse loop.

Answer (score 1):

This question is basically the same: 
[How can I reverse a NSArray in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586370/how-can-i-reverse-a-nsarray-in-objective-c)

You might want to try this:

```
NSArray * copy = [[array reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
```

It is also worth noting that iterating over a dictionary does not guarantee a certain order.