# Join NSArray into String

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

If I have an array with the following:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"dog", "brown", "kid"];
```

And I loop over that

```
for (NSString *strings in [array reverseObjectEnumerator] { }
```

How do I join that those individual words in one final string?

Comment: Please make some effort to search or look at the docs for `NSArray`.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray* reversedArray = [[array reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
[reversedArray componentsJoinedByString:" "]
```

See more at link: [How can I reverse a NSArray in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586370/how-can-i-reverse-a-nsarray-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0):

Don't loop over them. Just use:

```
[array componentsJoinedByString:" "]
```

... assuming you want a space between each word.

Comment: Have to loop over them because I am reversing them first.

Comment: Certainly the functional way would be to loop over the one array, reversing words and depositing them in a second array, then join the second array to make the output string.

Comment: trying to do that now. Cannot figure out how to make the output string.