# UIPickerView change/reverse scroll direction

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I have a UIPickerView that contains values 0-100. When I scroll up, it ascends accordingly (0, 1, 2, etc.) (see attached image)

Is it possible to scroll **down** and have the numbers ascend that way?

Essentially I want to reverse scroll for the UIPickerView so in the provided image, the numbers would be reversed and as I scroll down the numbers will increase up to 100.

On `viewDidLoad` I tried

```
    [self.pickerView selectRow:100 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
```

However that just goes straight to 100 in the same manner.

[image: picker view scrolling]

Comment: if I understood correctly, why don't you reverse the part of the datasource. Instead of giving the string value for the row to "rowNumber %", give "100-rowNumber %"?

Comment: @Larme that was the original solution I had however, I did not mention the numbers are not always 0-100. I can have different arrays of numbers (i.e. 0, 25, 25, 50, 80, 100) and they would not be consecutive

Comment: Just reverse the array then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586370/how-can-i-reverse-a-nsarray-in-objective-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you reverse the order of the numbers in the data source and then set the initial selection to the last row. That combination gives you what you want.

I also recommend implementing (or finding a 3rd party implementation) a "circular" picker view. See the minute column of the picker view used on the Timer tab of the standard Clock app for an example of what I mean.